# My script is throwing an invalid DIRhandle error

Tags: perl

My problem is for some reason I'm getting two errors when I run my script:

> readdir() attempted on invalid dirhandle DIR at spreadsheet.pl line 206.
> closedir() attempted on invalid dirhandle DIR at spreadsheet.pl line 254.

#### My code

```
use warnings 'all';
use strict;

use LWP::Simple 'get';
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;
use Path::Tiny;
use constant URL => 'http://pastebin.com/raw/qLwu80ZW';

my $teamNumber = "";my $teamName="";my $schoolName="";my $area="";my $district=""; my $agDeptPhone=""; my $schoolPhone=""; my $fax=""; my $addressOne=""; my $addressTwo=""; my $city=""; 
my $state=""; my $zipCode=""; my $name=""; my $email=""; my $row=""; my $Ypos=0; 

my $workbook  = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('perlOutput.xlsx');
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();

sub getTeamNumber {
    my ($file) = @_;
    my $html = path($file)-> slurp;
    my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($html);
    my @nodes = $tree->look_down(_tag => 'input');
    my $val;
    foreach my $node (@nodes) {
        $val = $node->look_down('name', qr/\$txt_TeamNumber/)->attr('value');
    }
    return $val;
}
sub getTeamName {
    my ($file) = @_;
    my $html = path($file)->slurp;
    my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($html);
    my @nodes = $tree->look_down(_tag => 'input');
    my $val;
    foreach my $node (@nodes) {
        $val = $node->look_down('name', qr/\$txt_TeamName/)->attr('value');
    }
    return $val;
}
sub getSchoolName {
    my ($file) = @_;
    my $html = path($file)->slurp;
    my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($html);
    my @nodes = $tree->look_down(tag_ => 'input');
    my $val;
    foreach my $node (@nodes) {
        $val = $node->look_down('name', qr/\$txt_SchoolName/)->attr('value');
    }
    return $val;
}
sub getArea{
    my ($file) = @_;
    my $html = path($file)->slurp;
    my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($html);
    my @nodes = $tree->look_down(tag_ => 'input');
    my $val;
    foreach my $node (@nodes) {
        $val = $node->look_down('name', qr/\$txt_Area/)->attr('value');
    }
    return $val;
}
sub getDistrict{
    my ($file) = @_;
    my $html = path($file)->slurp;
    my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($html);
    my @nodes = $tree->look_down(_tag => 'input');
    my $val;
    foreach my $node (@nodes) {
        $val = $node->look_down('name', qr/\$txt_District/)->attr('value');
    }
    return $val;
}
sub getDeptPhone{
    my ($file) = @_;
    my $html = path($file)->slurp;
    my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($html);
    my @nodes = $tree->look_down(_tag => 'input');
    my $val;
    foreach my $node (@nodes) {
        $val = $node->look_down('name', qr/\$txt_Phone/)->attr('value');
    }
    return $val;
}
sub getSchoolPhone{
    my ($file) = @_;
    my $html = path($file)->slurp;
    my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($html);
    my @nodes = $tree->look_down(_tag => 'input');
    my $val;
    foreach my $node (@nodes) {
        $val = $node->look_down('name', qr/\$txt_Phone2/)->attr('value');
    }
    return $val;
}
sub getFax{
    my ($file) = @_;
    my $html = path($file)->slurp;
    my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($html);
    my @nodes = $tree->look_down(_tag => 'input');
    my $val;
    foreach my $node (@nodes) {
        $val = $node->look_down('name', qr/\$txt_Fax/)->attr('value');
    }
    $val =~ s/\-//g;
    return $val;
}
sub getAddress1 {
    my ($file) = @_;
    my $html = path($file)-> slurp;
    my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($html);
    my @nodes = $tree->look_down(_tag => 'input');
    my $val;
    foreach my $node (@nodes) {
        $val = $node->look_down('name', qr/\$txt_Address1/)->attr('value');
    }
    return $val;
}
sub getAddress2 {
    my ($file) = @_;
    my $html = path($file)-> slurp;
    my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($html);
    my @nodes = $tree->look_down(_tag => 'input');
    my $val;
    foreach my $node (@nodes) {
        $val = $node->look_down('name', qr/\$txt_Address2/)->attr('value');
    }
    return $val;
}
sub getCity {
    my ($file) = @_;
    my $html = path($file)-> slurp;
    my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($html);
    my @nodes = $tree->look_down(_tag => 'input');
    my $val;
    foreach my $node (@nodes) {
        $val = $node->look_down('name', qr/\$txt_City/)->attr('value');
    }
    return $val;
}
sub getState {
    my ($file) = @_;
    my $html = path($file)-> slurp;
    my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($html);
    my @nodes = $tree->look_down(_tag => 'input');
    my $val;
    foreach my $node (@nodes) {
        $val = $node->look_down('name', qr/\$txt_State/)->attr('value');
    }
    return $val;
}
sub getZip {
    my ($file) = @_;
    my $html = path($file)-> slurp;
    my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($html);
    my @nodes = $tree->look_down(_tag => 'input');
    my $val;
    foreach my $node (@nodes) {
        $val = $node->look_down('name', qr/\$txt_Zip/)->attr('value');
    }
    return $val;
}
sub getWebsite {
    my ($file) = @_;
    my $html = path($file)-> slurp;
    my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($html);
    my @nodes = $tree->look_down(_tag => 'input');
    my $val;
    foreach my $node (@nodes) {
        $val = $node->look_down('name', qr/\$txt_Website/)->attr('value');
    }
    return $val;
}
sub getNameAndEmail {
my ($file) = @_;
    my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content(get URL);
    my ($table) = $tree->look_down(_tag => 'table', class => 'rgMasterTable');
    
    for my $tr ( $table->look_down(_tag => 'tr') ) {
        next unless my @td = $tr->look_down(_tag => 'td');
        my ($name, $email) = map { $_->as_trimmed_text } @td[0,1];
}
    return ($name, $email);
}
        
#FILLER: This fills the spreadsheet with all the variables we've acquired
sub fill {
    my ($name, $email, $teamNumber, $teamName, $schoolName, $area, $district, 
        $agDeptPhone, $schoolPhone, $fax, $addressOne, $addressTwo, $city, $state, $zipCode) = (@_);
    $worksheet->write($Ypos, 1, $name);
    $worksheet->write($Ypos, 2, $email);
    $worksheet->write($Ypos, 3, $teamNumber);
    $worksheet->write($Ypos, 4, $teamName);
    $worksheet->write($Ypos, 5, $schoolName);
    $worksheet->write($Ypos, 6, $area);
    $worksheet->write($Ypos, 7, $district);
    $worksheet->write($Ypos, 8, $agDeptPhone);
    $worksheet->write($Ypos, 9, $schoolPhone);
    $worksheet->write($Ypos, 10, $fax);
    $worksheet->write($Ypos, 11, $addressOne);
    $worksheet->write($Ypos, 12, $addressTwo);
    $worksheet->write($Ypos, 13, $city);
    $worksheet->write($Ypos, 14, $state);
    $worksheet->write($Ypos, 15, $zipCode);
        }

#Open judgingcard directory
opendir DH, '/Judging Card' or die "Unable to open directory '/Judging Card': $!";
my @files = readdir(DIR);
    
    #This fills out all top row info
    $worksheet->write("A1","Name");
    $worksheet->write("B1","Email");
    $worksheet->write("C1","Team Number");
    $worksheet->write("D1","Team Name");
    $worksheet->write("E1","School Name");
    $worksheet->write("F1","Area");
    $worksheet->write("G1","District");
    $worksheet->write("H1","Ag Dept Phone");
    $worksheet->write("I1","School Phone");
    $worksheet->write("J1","Fax");
    $worksheet->write("K1","Address One");
    $worksheet->write("L1","Address Two");
    $worksheet->write("M1","City");
    $worksheet->write("N1","State");
    $worksheet->write("O1","Zip Code");
    ###################################

    
foreach my $file (@files) { #run through all files in directory
    next if (-d $file); #Skip file if file is folder
        
        $Ypos = $Ypos + 1;
        
        my ($name1, $email1) = getNameAndEmail($file);
        
        $name = $name1;
        $email = $email1;
        $teamNumber = getTeamNumber($file);
        $teamName = getTeamName($file);
        $schoolName = getSchoolName($file);
        $area = getArea($file);
        $district = getDistrict($file);
        $agDeptPhone = getDeptPhone($file);
        $schoolPhone = getSchoolPhone($file);
        $fax = getFax($file);
        $addressOne = getAddress1($file);
        $addressTwo = getAddress2($file);
        $city = getCity($file);
        $state = getState($file);
        $zipCode = getZip($file);
        
        fill($name, $email, $teamNumber, $teamName, $schoolName, $area, $district, $agDeptPhone, $schoolPhone, $fax, $addressOne, 
            $addressTwo, $city, $state, $zipCode);
        
}
closedir(DIR);`
```

Comment: Please don't just dump your error messages and the entirety of your code and tell us to get on with it. It's very rude of you of you apart from anything else. Take a look at [*How to Ask*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and particularly at [*How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I apologize. I'll for sure do better next time.

Comment: I'm unclear why you've altered the code in your question to match my solution? And why have you changed `closedir(DH)` to `closedir(DIR)` when `DIR` never existed in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Lines 206 and 254 are

```
my @files = readdir(DH);
```

and

```
closedir(DH);
```

after this `opendir`

```
opendir(DH, "\/Judging Card\/");
```

The first thing you should do is to *check the status* of your `opendir`. That will tell you immediately why the directory handle is invalid

Like this

```
opendir DH, '/Judging Card/' or die qq{Unable to open directory "/Judging Card/": $!};
```

The first thing that troubles me is that `Judging Card` doesn't look like a root directory name, but by preceding it with a slash (you don't need to escape slashes inside quotes) you are saying that it's at the root of the filing system. But the error message from that `or die` will tell you the problem

Comment: I updated my code to try and fix the errors, but I still am getting the same errors. Also updated the code in my thread

Comment: That's very hard to believe. If `opendir` didn't throw an error then `readdir` on the same handle will succeed except in the most extraordinary of cases. Are you sure you're running the file with the changes that you made?